# Eclipse error database connection

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

What should I do?Thanks

```
  import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

 Public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
 {
 private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = ""; 
private static String DB_NAME ="finala";// Database name
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) 
{
  super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
  if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
   DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";         
}
 else
 {
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
 }
 this.mContext = context;
 }   

 public void createDataBase() throws IOException
 {
//If database not exists copy it from the assets

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
if(!mDataBaseExist)
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    this.close();
    try 
    {
        //Copy the database from assests
        copyDataBase();
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
    } 
    catch (IOException mIOException) 
    {
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
    }
   }
   }
//Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}

//Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
  {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
    {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}

//Open the database, so we can query it
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
     mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null,   SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    return mDataBase != null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() 
{
    if(mDataBase != null)
        mDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

}
  public class DataHelper {

}
```

And the errors are:

```
-The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)
-Breakpoint:DataBaseHelper
-The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase,int,int)
-Syntax error on token "Public" public expected
-The public type DataBaseHelper must be defined in it's own file.
```

Comment: Please add paste your code and errors here.

Comment: Link you provide is not for public link please paste code in question soo user can read and give proper solutions.

Comment: So, you have written down every error you have. Why not just fixing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper

That is not "Public"

"public" please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` from `SqliteOpenHelper`

Because `SqliteOpenHelper` is an abstract class. Whenever you extends an abstract class you need to override (implement) the abstract methods of it.

Read the [`SQLiteHelper` class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).

Comment: And I have a question: Why do you give me negative marks?I'm a newbie in this area,i'm only 15 years old,I only make programming for almost one year..

Comment: I haven't, I gave you the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.I resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> -The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)

You need to add

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
```

with some implementation that creates your database schema in case the database file was just created.

> -Breakpoint:DataBaseHelper

There's a breakpoint on the line. This is not an error, just a message.

> -The type DatabaseHelper must implement the inherited abstract method SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase,int,int)

You need to add

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
```

as the method that updates your database schema. You can leave it empty at first.

> -Syntax error on token "Public" public expected

Use `public` with lowercase `p`.

> -The public type DataBaseHelper must be defined in it's own file.

Package-level public class sources must be in a file that matches the class name. `DataHelper` and `DataBaseHelper` do not match; rename the other.

---

Overall, it looks like you're trying to use a prepopulated database. Consider using [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) library for that instead of attempting to copy a flawed example you've found somewhere.